# restore ajax dynamically added content on back button

Tags: html, ajax, back-button

I have a very simple scenario. A web page with a list of items which invokes ajax call upon clicking on any item and dynamically add some text to the page.
Now, obviously, if I leave this page and then I press the back button I get the initial list without all the dynamically added text.

I've been reading a lot about this issue. There are a many tricks to preserve the information and/or load it again from server. But it seems to me that this really simple and desired behaviour should have a simple solution without the need for any trick or server re-loading which will result in obvious noticeable delay for the user.

So, does anyone know about a simple way to get back to the page via back button and retain all the dynamically added parts without the need to load them again from the server?

Comment: Using local storage is an option.

Comment: @Sajeev Thank you. This does seems like an option. But I'm asking myself, since this is such a simple desired behaviour, how do everybody do that? what is the best practice?

Comment: @dsb I don't think it is that "simple". Not that it is hard to achieve, but it requires some effort - don't underestimate the task.